# Is there geometrical isomerism in case of 2-methylcyclopentanone?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism

How can 2-methylcyclopentanone show geometrical isomerism?
A ring and a double bond are in different planes, so even after having restricted rotation there will be no change in areal distance.

Comment: The 5 C ring isn't flat.

Comment: The bonds C=O and C(1) - C(2) defines a reference plane. The methyl substituent may be above or under this horizontal plane. These two possibilities define two optical isomers.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the structure of 2-methylcyclopentanone, you'll notice that it is asymmetric about the C-2 atom

[image]

This gives rise to two isomers; the *R* isomer on the left and the *S* isomer on the right

[image]

These are definitely optical isomers, more specifically enantiomers of each other. Whether these are 'geometric isomers' or not is a matter of how you define 'geometric' isomerism; the IUPAC Gold Book [strongly discourages the usage of this term](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/G02620), instead preferring to use '[*cis-trans* isomerism](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/C01093)'. If it is defined by the latter, then **this compound does not display cis-trans isomerism**, as there are no groups for the methyl substituent to be *trans* to.

Comment: @NiveditaChowdhury Please don't post a "thank you" as a comment. Instead, [upvote](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) or [accept](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) answers that were useful to you.

Comment: This answer is partially correct. The fact that there is optical isomerism does not cancel the fact that being the ring non planar, the methyl and the oxygen can point both up or to "opposite" directions. This call for an analysis of conformers.